# Loading Nested Placeholders from Properties File with Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

Is it possible to load nested placeholders from within a properties file? I am trying to load a URL dynamically.

For instance, if my properties file contains

```
my.url=http://localhost:8888/service/{nestedProperty}/
```

Is there a way to load in values for {nestedProperty} at runtime? Similar to the behavior of a ResourceBundle. If so, how would would I be able to effectively instantiate the String? So far I'm thinking

```
<bean id="myURLString" class="java.lang.String" scope="prototype" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="URL" value="${my.url}" />
</bean>
```

...but I'm not sure what properties to nest. I'd like to get a bean using Annotations if possible, although I currently have something along the lines of

```
ctx.getBean("myURLString", String.class, new Object[] { nestedProperty} );
```

I've looked into PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and several other properties file questions on here, but I can't seem to figure out if this is even possible.

I should also note that I want to load this nested property dynamically from within my code, or at least manipulate them from there (possibly via @PostConstruct?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

```
my.url=http://localhost:8888/service/${nestedProperty}
nestedProperty=foo/bar/baz
```

Add in the dollar sign in front of the braces in your example and you're set!

To actually use the fully resolved property, do this:

```
@Value("${my.url}")
private String url;
```

in a Spring bean.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to explicitly define this property in my bean definition somehow?

Comment: 'nestedProperty' refers to the property of that name - the second line of the example - not a bean. Spring loads all the properties in all the configured files and resolves them against each other. As long as you avoid circular references you are fine.

Comment: Does this allow me to dynamically specify the nested properties from the ctx.getBean() call rather than using the properties file value of 'nestedProperty'?

Comment: See my update; you never actually have to think of the property as a bean, you can inject it directly with @Value