# Does Spring support nested properties across multiple properties files?

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I'd like to separate properties across multiple files and allow files loaded later to have properties that refer or combine properties defined previously (nested). For example:

application.properties (e.g. dbName=test, dbHost=targethost)
mysql.properties (e.g. jdbcDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://${dbHost:localhost):${dbPort:3306}/${dbName})

And I use declarations such as:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" order="0" ignore-unresolvable="false"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:${dbType:mysql}.properties" order="1" ignore-unresolvable="false"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbcDriver}"/>
```

When I try to create a dataSource in Spring config I get an error saying that ${dbName} or ${jdbcDriver} is unresolved.

For example:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbcDriver' in string value "${jdbcDriver}";
```

Could someone shed light if it is possible to organize properties into different files in this fashion, and if so, how to configure Spring to resolve the properties properly so my bean declaration does not fail?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may use maven resources plugin to filter nest properties. PS: I suppose properties like ${name:default} are not supported in .properties file?

Comment: Not only that, @hsluo, but if you have three properties files, and C refers to properties in B, and likewise B refers to properties in A, none of the properties in B or C get resolved. Looking for a basic example on how to make this work, or abandon and use Guice or some other Spring alternative instead.

Comment: User error on my part. I had an unterminated ${ . There was a typo where the terminating character was ) instead of }. Hard to see and took a day to diagnose.

Comment: so the example works?

Comment: yes. one of the files had a typo, and the error messages were not all that helpful. i did find other problems associated with context:property-placeholder, a known bug of some two years where they just don't work: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9989. The upside of the XML and placeholder stuff, keep all the config out of the code. The tradeoffs as I see them, the boat anchor (Spring) that is easy to get wrong and hard to diagnose, or the mini bike (Guava) that needs lots of add-ons to make it useable in any practical sense.

Comment: My choice... I will likely to go with Spring, I don't have time to waste retrofiting placeholder support on top of Guava, and what Guava has for bolt-ons is pretty crappy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading Nested Placeholders from Properties File with Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160607/loading-nested-placeholders-from-properties-file-with-spring)